# No factors of Characteristic Polynomial are the Minimal Polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to compute the Jordan canonical form for the matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
9 & 4 & 5    \\
-4 & 0 & -3  \\
-6 & -4 & -2
\end{pmatrix}. $$
My first step was to compute the characteristic polynomial and then, from that, find the minimal polynomial. But finding the minimal polynomial is proving to be somewhat of a challenge for some reason. Observe:

Let $A$ be the given matrix. Then, the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(x)$ is given by the determinant of $xI - A$. Thus,
$$ \chi_A(x) = x^3 - 7x^2 + 16x - 12 = (x-3)(x-2)^2. $$
So, the minimal polynomial $m_A(x)$ must be either $(x-3)(x-2)$ or $(x-3)(x-2)^2$. But,
$$ (A-3I)(A-2I) =  \begin{pmatrix}
42 & 16 & 25    \\
16 & 6 & 9  \\
36 & 16 & 20
\end{pmatrix} \ne \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0    \\
0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}. $$
And, similarly, 
$$ (A-3I)(A-2I)^2 =  \begin{pmatrix}
294 & 64 & 125    \\
-64 & -12 & -27  \\
-216 & -64 & -80
\end{pmatrix} \ne \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0    \\
0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}. $$
Does this matrix not have a minimal polynomial, or something? Is such a thing even possible? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should check your calculation of $(A-3I)(A-2I)$ and $(A-3I)(A-2I)^2$.

Comment: @sharding4 Hmm, I did, and I actually got something different. But it's still not the zero matrix. Not sure what's going on here. Are you telling me that this should, indeed, be the minimal polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get

\begin{align*}
A-3I &= \pmatrix{
 6&4&5\cr
 -4&-3&-3\cr
 -6&-4&-5\cr
 } \\
A-2I &= \pmatrix{
 7&4&5\cr
 -4&-2&-3\cr
 -6&-4&-4\cr
 } \\
(A-3I)(A-2I) &= \pmatrix{
 -4&-4&-2\cr
 2&2&1\cr
 4&4&2\cr
 } \\
(A-3I)(A-2I)^2 &= \pmatrix{
 0&0&0\cr
 0&0&0\cr
 0&0&0\cr
 }
\end{align*}

Comment: Ok, so I understand that matrix multiplication is not necessarily commutative, but the fact that squaring the $A-2I$ term and then (left) multiplying the result by $A-3I$ gives me the wrong answer seems a bit bizarre...

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude    That shouldn't be a problem.  $\pmatrix{
 6&4&5\cr
 -4&-3&-3\cr
 -6&-4&-5\cr
 }\pmatrix{
 3&0&3\cr
 -2&0&-2\cr
 -2&0&-2\cr
 } = \pmatrix{
 0&0&0\cr
 0&0&0\cr
 0&0&0\cr
 }$
but you should simply multiply $(A-3I)(A-2I)$ on the right by $A-2I$

Comment: Oh, hell, I see where I went wrong. Just made a stupid arithmetic error, of course... Thanks.